# What's the correct way to puncuate "Now, on with the show!"?

Tags: phrases

Title says it all. When I say it, I often pause after now. Not sure if it's correct to have the comma there or not.

Comment: You don't mean 'spell'; you mean 'punctuate'.

Comment: @petershor That's so meta. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pause after the ***Now***, when saying ***Now, on with the show!***, then putting in a comma indicates that pause.

It isn't right or wrong to include or omit the comma. But (IMHO), most people would probably pause after the *Now* (as you do), do it's probably better to include the comma.

Comment: Technically, it's not really a pause; it's more likely a lengthening of _Now_, with an intonation dip of mid-high-low-mid, as in counting: 38, 39, 40, 41, etc. A spectrograph normally does not record any silences in speech.

Comment: Now let's think about this... I can include the [optional] comma there or not, depending whether I'm making a measured observation, or a hasty interjection. But in *my* "inner voice", OP's construction sounds more like ["Now be off with you!"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22now+be+off+with+you%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), where it seems to me the vast majority of writers have chosen ***not*** to include a comma.

Comment: I would also point out that I don't often pause after 'now' when I say 'Now be off with you!'. :)

Answer (score 0):

A per def. 2 of [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/now) the *now* you are using is to get attention to the rest of the sentence, in a conversational manner. Hence, both the examples in my link have a comma after the *now*.

> Used, especially in conversation, to draw attention to a particular statement or point in a narrative:
>
> *now, my first impulse was to run away*
>
> *I don’t like Scotch. Now, if it had been Irish Whiskey you’d offered me**